# From virtual machine, access web application on host

Tags: windows, iis, virtualization

I have a Windows Vista 64 bit system (A) which is hosting a Windows XP 32 bit virtual machine (B).

I need to call a web page hosted on A, from B (IIS 7).    B can't access A.  I get a "currently unavailable" error message.  B can ping A.  B can map a drive on A.  B can't browse a web page on A.

I can do the reverse (Call B from A), but that doesn't do me any good.

I imagine it's a security or firewall issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Can other clients view the webpage? If you can map a network drive using the builtin Windows tools from B to A then you have communication going smoothly between them-and almost any firewall (unless its been tweaked) would block SMB traffic and allow web-so my first suspicion is that your web server isn't serving the page properly to any clients.

Comment: I can view and call the page on the physical hardware itself.  I haven't tried from other physical machines.

Comment: Try other machines-you may not be able to access it from anywhere except local host. Are you using IIS or Apache?

Comment: IIS.  Where do I configure it to remove "localhost only" behavior?

Comment: First step-either disable the Windows firewall completely via the control panel applet, or make an exception for IIS. Since you're not using the server version of IIS you shouldn't have to do too much tweaking-its designed to be pretty much plug and play.